# Layout not adjusting when soft keyboard pops up

Tags: android

I have a FrameLayout which is the child of ScrollView, 
I set an image as frame layout background and draw dynamic EditText on random coordinates of framelayout by setting x and y coordinates of EditText. The issue is when an edittext behind the  keyboard gets focus, the layout doesn't scroll up. I have to scroll it manually and as soon as i start typing the layout scroll back to original position.

Instead of FrameLayout, if i take LinearLayout with vertical orientation and add edittext dynamically(without setting coordinates), it works perfectly.

"AsjustPan" is already set in manifest file.

Here is the test layout and java file which works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/sv_root"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_canvas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout layout_canvas = findViewById(R.id.layout_canvas);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ppd);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, 1908, false);
        layout_canvas.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), scaledBitmap));

        for(int i=0; i<50; i++){
            EditText editText = new EditText(this);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,100);
            layoutParams.topMargin = 10;
            editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            layout_canvas.addView(editText);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the test layout and java file which doesn't works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/sv_root"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_canvas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </FrameLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FrameLayout layout_canvas = findViewById(R.id.layout_canvas);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ppd);

        Bitmap sBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, 1908, false);
        layout_canvas.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), sBitmap));


        int y = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<60; i++){
            EditText editText = new EditText(this);
            editText.setX(20);
            editText.setY(y);

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 80);
            layout_canvas.addView(editText, layoutParams);
            y = y + 100;
        }

    }
}
```

Can someone help me with this issue. Thanks

Comment: How is your activity declared in AndroidManifest.xml? It's this declaration that controls what happens when the soft keyboard pops out.

Comment: No i am not handling anything when soft keyboard pops up.

Comment: You are saying `AdjustPan is already in the manifest layout`. Change that to `AdjustResize` and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: @AleksG No, even adjustResize not working.